# 4D Fourier transform of $\theta(t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Possibly this post of mine is bad style in that I am not a Mathematica user, at least not yet; rather I use the competing Maple. My excuse, if at all acceptable to the present community, is that another Maple user on mapleprimes.com (the help forum on Maple) has posted a Mathematica result which completely surprises me; in fact, I think the result is wrong.

The result concerns the 4-dimensional generalized (i.e., distributional) Fourier transformation of $\theta(t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2)$ in Minkowski space, where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function, this quantity equaling $1$ inside the light cone, $1/2$ on the light cone, and $0$ outside the light cone.

The result Mathematica assertedly returns has the form $4\pi^2 \delta(E)\delta(p_x)\delta(p_y)\delta(p_z)$, see end of the post http://mapleprimes.com/questions/214176-4D-Fourier-Transform#comment229800; in keeping with standard physics notation, I have renamed $w1,w2,w3,w4$ to $E,p_x,p_y,p_z$. But that cannot be correct, I guess, as only constants have such Fourier transformations, or am I fundamentally mistaken?

I would therefore very much appreciate to have this Mathematica result corroborated. Thanks.

Comment: Judging from that post I'm guessing you no longer require an answer, but that is in fact the answer that Mathematica produces for this input.

Comment: I can also confirm that MM produces that output on my system (MM 10.4.1 on OSX.)  Whether or not it is a correct or meaningful answer is another question.

Comment: Feyre and Seifert, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I agree the result given by *Mathematica* doesn't make sense because the `InverseFourierTransform` doesn't lead back to the input. However, since the result will definitely contain delta functions, you *have* to eventually use it inside another integral anyway. I would suggest calculating **that integral** directly instead of going through the FT.

Comment: By the way, looking at the linked discussion in the Q, the Wikipedia equation (2) is definitely correct. Of course you can write down formal function limits of the delta "function" that don't seem to factorize, but their effects are exactly the same as the factorized form - and the effect is what counts because `DiracDelta` is a distribution, not a function..

Comment: @Jens: Thanks a lot for your comments. I am happy to hear that what I have always thought to be correct, the Wikipedia Eq. (2), is in fact correct. I am also happy to hear that you, too, think that the result Mathematica returns is wrong (is that bug something to look into?). As I have written in the Maple thread, I think the correct result has the form $a \delta^{(4)}(k) + b \mathrm{Pf}(1/(k \cdot k)^2)$, with $a,b$ constants, $k = (E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ the momentum four-vector, and $\mathrm{Pf}$ the pseudo function. My problem is that the constants depend on the integration order; clearly wrong.